# How to Resolve issue "State Mismatch" in react native app login authentication of Microsoft using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, react-native, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to login using Microsoft Graph apis to get user access token and details.But when I'm tyring to enter email and hit next,an error appears as screenshot below[image]

Comment: Please let us know which package you are using and also looks like a similar issue raised in [Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1035)

Comment: "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^2.0.0" On android its working fine but on ios it has that error message.I'm adding this redirect url for ios urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Comment: Please update the screenshot with the error code

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question